# Remember search/replace strings across sessions

Tags: emacs

Is there a setting in emacs to remember the search/replace string across multiple sessions?

```
%> emacs -nw fileA
<replace X with Y>

%> emacs -nw fileB
<replace>
```

should automatically replace `X` with `Y` (without having to enter both again)

Comment: The `desktop.el` library (when activated) creates a destop file when killing Emacs, which when opened reveals a `(setq search-ring . . .` and `(setq regexp-search-ring . . .`, among other saved settings.  However, I've never tried to do what you are proposing -- perhaps its worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

There's `savehist-mode` specifically for that kind of saving/restoring:

```
(savehist-mode 1)
(add-to-list 'savehist-additional-variables 'query-replace-defaults)
```

Comment: savehist-mode must come last for the settings to take

Comment: @vfclists: What makes you think so?  The way you changed the code, it signals an error because `savehist-additional-variables` is a void variable at the time the `add-to-list` is executed.

Comment: In the examples I see` (savehist-mode 1)` is placed after the `add-to-list` command. I think initialization must be done via M-x in a live Emacs session, but in the `init.el` it has to come after the `add-to-list` commands